# How to skew or linearly scale font height in a word in CSS

Tags: css, transform, scale, perspective, skew

I need to scale down the font height like below image.

[image: I need to scale down the font height like below image.]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `rotateY` function on the element containing the text. Here's an example:

```
.class-name {
    transform: rotateY(30deg);
}
```

Comment: Hi @dan, as you see in above picture the font-size of "G" is greater than 'D' in the word 'GET COPD'. I need to achieve font size decrease linearly in the word.

Comment: In that case, rotate it around the Y axis `transform: rotateY(30deg)`

Comment: unfortunately it couldn't help to achieve like the above image.